# Using a specific method inside a scope query rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have in database something called `device`
And I want to extract from the database devices that Semantic Version is greater/equal than '1.2.42' and if the device status is online

I have a method

```
def check_sem_ver
    basic_sem_version = "1.2.42"
    device_base_ver = Device.harware_info["software-version"].split("-").first
    return Gem::Version.new(device_base_ver) >= Gem::Version.new(basic_sem_version)
end
```

As well as I have a scope called

`scope :proper_sem_version, -> { where(online-status: 'online).and(check_sem_ver) }`

But this does not work, how can I extract something from the database only if `check_sem_ver` is true?
Unfortunately basic maths inside where like `where(software-version > '1.2.42')` does not work because version is a string with `-` as you can see that I have to split to get rid of.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use a ruby method to filter records inside of the database. You can fetch all records into the app and filter them there, but it is less efficient.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, in general what you say is true. However if the ruby method returns a single value, such as in this example, you can indeed include it in the query. See my answer.

Comment: @LesNightingill: In your example, the method can return whatever (array, for example) and you can still use its return value to build a query. Because it's just that, a value. No different from a local variable or hardcoded literal. I agree with your proposed approach of changing things up to try make the DB do the work, but it's not "using a ruby method in an SQL query".

Answer (score 0):

For the expected comparison of version strings, they need to be converted into arrays.

If you're using Postgres, you can structure a scope like this:

```rb
BasicSemVersion = "1.2.42"

def query_threshold
  BasicSemVersion.split('.').join(',')
end

scope :proper_sem_version, -> { where("online-status='online' and string_to_array(software-version,'.')::int[]>=ARRAY[#{query_threshold}]") }
```